# Ruby OpenStates NoMethodError - undefined method `map'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having issues with a Ruby gem that used to work, but now doesn't.  It's openstates https://rubygems.org/gems/openstates .  The code to find Legislators doesn't seem to work anymore.  We have had this code in production for a while, but are now getting this error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `map' for #<String:0x007ff0b51941c0>

openstates (0.0.1) lib/openstates/model.rb:37:in `where'
```

This is the how we are calling the method.

```
OpenStates::Legislator.where(parameters)

parameters = {:state=>"Ca"}
```

Comment: If it was working and now is not, this may occurred due to an update you have done to your gems and the latest version had an error, specify the version of this gem that is not buggy in your gemfile and that should work

Comment: It's still the same version of the gem I've been using all along. Version 0.0.1

Comment: I suggest you replace your tag `Rubygems` with `gem` and either  `openstates` or `OpenStates`.

Comment: Try to pass the parameters like this: `parameters = {:state=>["CA"]}`

Comment: The gem hasn't been updated for over 3 years so something must have changed in your code. Just as a side note, using gems that old is highly discouraged.

Comment: I haven't changed my code

Comment: Then the api must have changed and the gem is no longer working since it hasn't been updated to match changes in the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code hasn't changed, the gem hasn't changed, but the API probably has.

Here's a very basic module to help you get an Array from `OpenStates::Legislator.where(parameters)` :

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'active_support/core_ext/object'

module OpenStates
  class Legislator
    @cache={}
    class << self
      def where(parameters)
        url = "https://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/?#{parameters.to_query}"
        @cache[url] ||= get_json(url)
      end

      private

      def get_json(url)
        puts "# Downloading #{url}"
        sleep 2
        JSON.load(open(url))
      end
    end
  end
end

parameters = {:state=>"Ca"}
p OpenStates::Legislator.where(parameters).first(2)
```

It outputs :

```
# Downloading https://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/?state=Ca
[
    {
                  "last_name" => "Gatto",
                 "updated_at" => "2016-09-24 07:16:00",
         "nimsp_candidate_id" => nil,
                  "full_name" => "Mike Gatto",
                         "id" => "CAL000123",
                 "first_name" => "Mike",
                "middle_name" => "",
                   "district" => "43",
                    "chamber" => "lower",
                      "state" => "ca",
               "votesmart_id" => "120220",
                      "party" => "Democratic",
            "+capitol_office" => {
             "phone" => "(916) 319-2043",
            "street" => "P.O. Box 942849, Room 4140",
               "zip" => "94249-0043",
              "city" => "Sacramento"
        },
                    "all_ids" => [
            "CAL000123",
            "CAL000246",
            "CAL000246",
            "CAL000367"
        ],
                     "leg_id" => "CAL000123",
                     "active" => true,
        "transparencydata_id" => "76584a5322274b9b892642b7b6ae3db5",
                  "photo_url" => "http://assembly.ca.gov/sites/assembly.ca.gov/files/memberphotos/AD43.jpg",
          "+district_offices" => [
            {
                 "phone" => "(818) 240-6330",
                "street" => "300 East Magnolia, Suite 504",
                   "zip" => "91502",
                  "city" => "Burbank"
            }
        ],
                        "url" => "http://asmdc.org/members/a43",
                    "country" => "us",
                 "created_at" => "2012-01-31 19:25:09",
                      "level" => "state",
                  "+district" => "43",
                    "offices" => [
            {
                    "fax" => nil,
                   "name" => "Capitol Office",
                  "phone" => "916-319-2043",
                "address" => "P.O. Box 942849, Room 5136\nSacramento, CA 94249-0043",
                   "type" => "capitol",
                  "email" => nil
            },
            {
                    "fax" => nil,
                   "name" => "District Office",
                  "phone" => "818-558-3043",
                "address" => "300 East Magnolia Blvd, Suite 504\nBurbank, CA 91502",
                   "type" => "district",
                  "email" => nil
            }
        ],
                     "+party" => "Democratic",
                   "suffixes" => ""
    },
    {
                  "last_name" => "Gordon",
                 "updated_at" => "2016-09-24 07:16:01",
    ...
```